# Search & replace on all files in server

Tags: linux, ssh, command

I want to search for this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//example.com/file.php?zoneid=112" async data-cfasync="false"></script>
```

And remove it/replace it with blank.

What command line could I run on linux to search and replace this term on **all files** on the server?

Answer (score 2):

I have used a combination of `grep` and `sed`

```
string_to_replace='<script type="text/javascript" src="//example.com/file.php?zoneid=112" async data-cfasync="false"></script>'
```

First just run the `grep` statement to make sure you are matching the right string and file. If everything looks good, then run the following command;

```
grep -Inr "${string_to_replace}" | while read line; do filename=`echo $line | cut -d ":" -f 1`; line_no=`echo $line | cut -d ":" -f 2`; sed "${line_no}d" -i $filename; done
```

In `grep`, **-I** will ignore binaries, **-n** will print the line number and **-r** will do a recursive search.

Let me know if something is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` with `regex` and command `d` over the `file`:

```
sed -i '/regex/d' file
```

Next construction could help you to pass filenames with `find` to `sed`:

```
find . | xargs sed -i '/regex/d'
```

Be careful with debugging. :)